# Selecting hosts in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I wanted to run commands on specific hosts based on condition.

I have ansible hosts entry

```
 [myhost_list]  
  myfqdn1.net    156.65.235.23  
  myfqdn2.net    157.23.36.3  
  myfqdn3.net    65.23.36.3
```

**Scenario #1**
select first host in the above list and run some command

```
e.g., Run some command on 156.65.235.23
```

**Scenario #2**
select remaining host except first host in the above list and run some command

```
e.g Run some command on  157.23.36.3, 65.23.36.3
```

I have written the following playbook but no luck, i have tried to set a host name

```
- hosts: myhost_list
  tasks:
    - name: set host specific command          
        command: #some command#
        when: ansible_ssh_host == groups['myhost_list'][0]
    - name: set host specific command         
        command: #some command#
        when: ansible_ssh_host == groups['myhost_list'][1]
    - name: set host specific command
        command: #some command# 
        when: ansible_ssh_host == groups['myhost_list'][2]
```

Comment: Sorry misspelled, now i have corrected its name not hostname.

Comment: I am not able to select the hosts using when condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should try magic variables (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

```
- name: set host specific command          
    command: #some command#
    when: ansible_ssh_host in group_names
- name: set host specific command         
    command: #some command#
    when: ansible_ssh_host in group_names
- name: set host specific command
    command: #some command# 
    when: ansible_ssh_host in groups
```

Comment: let me try with your suggestion